# Why are python packages installed from a different index-url with pip?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I noticed on this page https://anaconda.org/pypi/urllib3 that the `pip` command to install the package was slightly different than normal:

```
pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/pypi/simple urllib3
```

Digging a bit through `pip`'s help I figured out the following which basically says that things are usually installed from https://pypi.python.org/simple.

Why is there a separate Python repository that Anaconda uses? I would've expected that you simply `pip install` anything but this seems to suggest there is a level of choice between the following two.

1. https://pypi.python.org/simple
2. https://pypi.anaconda.org/pypi/simple

   Package Index Options (including deprecated options):
     -i, --index-url        Base URL of Python Package Index (default
                                 https://pypi.python.org/simple). This should point to a
                                 repository compliant with PEP 503 (the simple
                                 repository API) or a local directory laid out in the
                                 same format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is there a separate Python repository that Anaconda uses?

Because Continuum IO (the maintainers of conda and Anaconda) decided that they wanted to have their own pip repository, I suppose. As far as I know, there's no difference between the two, except that possibly some package versions are different between the two repositories, or perhaps one repository has some packages that aren't present in the other.

In any case, in my experience, the `pip` that's installed by default with Anaconda searches the https://pypi.python.org/simple repository by default, and one has to manually include the `-i` option to get to the Anaconda pip repository.